# Expandable width of div in CSS

Tags: html, css, width

I am trying to make an expandable div that will have a minimum width of 200 px but will expand if the content is longer. the problem is the width always displays as 100%, If i put a `width: 200px` it will stay 200 and will not expand.

This is my CSS code for the div:

```
#section_title {
    background-color: #2b65ae;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 30px 0px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    font-size: 24px;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 8px #444444;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px #444444;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 8px #444444;
}
```

Comment: The way you mentioned your problem it can be solved using `min-width` but you have used it already in your css code. what is the problem?

Comment: @Mr_Green `min-width` in this case doesn't make the div `200px` and then only expand it when needed. `min-width` mean it cannot become smaller that `200px`, but in this case it will be `100%` of available width still.

Comment: Will removing  background-size: 100% 100%; work?

Comment: No background size won't affect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use display:table properties to achieve this :

Update your CSS with :

```
display:table;
width: 200px;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/J4TnF/)** , using just words and white-space to keep all on one line for the demo purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
div {
    float: left; /* or right according to your requirement */
    width: auto;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will keep the minimun width 200, will expand on more content and won't go beyond 100% width.

Comment: Won't work, width:auto will make the width 100% all the time.

Comment: use `float: left;` then it won't make it 100% all the time.

Comment: `display:table` solution is more efficient and clean, adding `float` just for that will more than likely means updating some of the parents CSS too and make it harder to have that div centered. It will make it expandable however, but requires more fiddling.

Comment: i don't understand why do you need to update css of parent for this and in question it isn't mentioned if the div is to be centered....  anyways whatever works for the person who asked :)

Comment: oh yeah indeed, just trying to point some issues one may have when using that way so they know the down side instead of wondering what cause the new defects if any created. `float` will make the element break out of the flow which can generate a fair amount of head scratching if you're not expecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
#section_title {
display:inline-block;
width: auto;
min-width: 200px;
max-width:100%;  
}
```

Updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/fNW7T/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for one line of content, then you can add a `float` to your css.

```
#section_title {
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(14,87,145);
    float: left;
}
```

Example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8kL6e/).